# Safari JavaScript Console Not Executing JS Or Showing Output On Certain Pages

Tags: debugging, safari

I've encountered a Safari-specific JS issue in a page I'm locally developing, so I need to use the Safari Web Inspector.

In Safari Version 13.1.1, when I open the inspector and select `Develop > Show JavaScript Console` and start entering JavaScript, I don't get any output and the JavaScript is not executed (e.g. an alert does not fire).

[image: picture of 2+2;, alert('okay!');, var myvar = 'foo'; in blue with no output]

On any other page, the safari JS console works just fine for me. Here's an example of normal behavior, on stackoverflow.com:

[image: picture of 2+2; with 4 output]

Note: the Safari JS console on other locally developed pages are working just fine.

What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: I found that if you reopen the file on a new tab, the new console evaluates

Comment: @kch You should make this comment an answer, because it resolves the issue, even if it doesn't explain the original behaviour.
I was having the same problem today and your comment helped me continue working.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Please report the problem to Apple via Feedback Assistant and any other method of submitting bug reports to Apple. I switched to Safari due to the scroll lag bug in Chrome on macOS that's been plaguing it for over a year now. I feel like I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place because I prefer macOS for everything else.

Answer (score 6):

As other users mentioned, opening the page in a new tab fixes this, but you can also just close the Javascript console (clicking the 'x' in the console window) and re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

Less than ideal, but if you reopen the file on a new tab, the new console works.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error. often, this is because I occasionally repeat something way too many times, so that it just stops executing the console, I believe to prioritize other code. my fix is to re-open the page, and  even though re-loading sounds like it works, it doesn't always.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).